# Tensoring sheaves generated by global sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a projective variety, and $Z$ be a closed subscheme of $X$ of dimension $0$. Let $A$ be an ample Cartier divisor of $X$ and $\mathcal{I}$ be the ideal sheaf of $Z$. From the definition of ideal sheaf, we have an exact sequence of sheaves

$\begin{equation}
0 \to \mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{O}_X \to i_*\mathcal{O}_Z \to 0,
\end{equation}$

where $i$ is the inclusion map $i: Z \to X$.

Tensoring with $\mathcal{O}_X(nA)$ for $n$ sufficient large, we obtain

$\begin{equation}
0 \to \mathcal{I}\otimes \mathcal{O}_X(nA) \to \mathcal{O}_X(nA) \to i_*\mathcal{O}_Z\otimes \mathcal{O}_X(nA)=i_*\mathcal{O}_Z \to 0.
\end{equation}
$

I wonder why the equality $i_*\mathcal{O}_Z\otimes \mathcal{O}_X(nA)=i_*\mathcal{O}_Z$ is true. I understand when $n$ is large enough, the very ampleness implies generated by global sections, but not sure what is the next step.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not true in general - try $X=\Bbb P^2$, $Z=V(X_0)\cong\Bbb P^1$, and $A$ the class of a hyperplane. Then the global sections of $i_*\mathcal{O}_Z$ are of dimension one, while the global sections of $i_*\mathcal{O}_Z(nA)$ are of dimension $n+1$ for $n>0$. Can you provide more details why you think this is true?

Comment: Is $Z$ zero-dimensional in your case? This is the only situation where this is true I can think of.

Comment: @IDC You are right, $Z$
 is dimension zero, I added to the question.

Comment: Any line bundle is locally free, in particular it is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}$ in a neighborhood of $Z$, hence tensor product with it is isomorphic to tensor product with $\mathcal{O}$, hence isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_Z$.

Comment: @Sasha You say "any line bundle", so then we don't really need $\mathcal{O}(nA)$ is generated by global sections?

Comment: @finiteness: Yes, global generation is absolutely irrelevant here.